# Basic authentication and form based authentication in the same application using Pac4J

Tags: pac4j

We are trying to use Pac4J with basic authentication and form authentication in the same application. The basic authentication (direct basic) will be used by a server to server communication and the form authentication will be used by a user through a web application. This works fine until the customer directly access a secure page, in that scenario an basic authentication popup will be shown in the browser.

The reason for the above is that the DefaultSecurityLogic first checks if an direct client supplies any credentials. In this scenario there are no credentials supplied. But the DirectBasicClient adds a response header (https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j/pull/1007) that triggers the browser to show an popup. Is there a reason for it that the DirectBasicClient always adds the WWW-authetication header? I think with this header present it harder to support multiple clients within the same application.

Kind regards,

Richard

Answer (score 0):

The header was added to conform to the spec: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617

This was not like that in the past. The header was only added for the `IndirectBasicAuthClient` and not for the `DirectBasicAuthClient`.

You can easily override the `DirectBasicAuthClient` with an empty `addAuthenticateHeader` method to avoid the popup.

Comment: Thanks, i fixed the issues in our product with the suggestion you made